# Chess engine on which to apply a custom-made OpenGL skin

Tags: opengl, chess

Is there any open source chess engine that I can use to practice my OpenGL skill-set? I think it would be a neat exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a look at [GNU Chess](http://www.gnu.org/software/chess/) . I'm not 100% sure, but I think there was a Python project that used GNU Chess as the AI "engine", so you can probably extend it to and make a 3D frontend.